# PHP and MySQL, array associated with 2 keys

Tags: php, mysql

I have this scenario.

I input $groupid="1";

**main table**

```
----------------------
| groupid  |  postid  |
|---------------------|
|       1  |       1  |
|       2  |       2  |
|       1  |       3  |

$query = "SELECT postid FROM `mainl` WHERE groupid='$groupid'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// a group of postids belonging to that groupid which should hold [1, 3] for groupid=1
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $postids[] = $row["postid"];
}
```

**second table**

```
-------------------------------------------
|  postid  |  commentid  |     comment    |
-------------------------------------------
|       1  |          1  |   testing 1    |
|       1  |          2  |   testing 2    |
|       1  |          3  |       what?    |
|       2  |          1  |       hello    |
|       2  |          2  | hello world    |
|       3  |          1  |      test 3    |
|       3  |          2  |       begin    |
|       3  |          3  |        why?    |
|       3  |          4  |       shows    |


$query = "SELECT * FROM `second`";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (in_array($row["postid"], $postids)) {
        $comments[$row["postid"]] = $row["comment"];
```

But how should I take care of commented
I want the postid array to be `[1,3]` and my comment array to be 
`[commentid: comment] [1:testing1, 2: testing2,  3: what?]` for `postid=1`
and
`[1:test3,  2:begin, 3: why? 4:shows]` for `postid=3`

how should be arrange everything such comment are associated with commentid and postid?

Comment: The mysql_* functions should not be used anymore, php has a newer, faster and more secure version to access mysql databases. mysqli_* functions should be used. More info and syntax can be found here. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: What should he use? I tried finding info on it in the php manual but couldnt find anything

Comment: You asked for two different things, a) a personalised array from each table and b) more simpler array derived from SQL query using join. Which one would you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

First I would follow rokdd suggestion and make 1 query

```
SELECT  m.groupid , s.postid, s.commentid, s.comment FROM `main1` m JOIN `second` s USING (postid) where m.groupid = 1
```

Then I would make a multi-dimensional array

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $groups[$row['groupid'][$row['postid']][$row['commentid']=$row['comment'];
```

then to iterate through the array

```
foreach($groups as $group)    
    foreach($group as $post)
        foreach($post as $comment)
           echo $comment;
```

This will keep track of groups also (if you ever want to select by more than 1 group.
If you don't care about groups just drop off the first part of the array.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $posts[$row['postid']][$row['commentid']=$row['comment'];


    foreach($posts as $post)
        foreach($post as $comment)
           echo $comment;
```

Comment: well @php side i was not sure what he like to do. before iterating to many times you can also make a key with a seperator and have one array: `$comments[$row['groupid'].'-'.$row['postid'].'-'.$row['commentid']]=$row['comment'];`

Answer (score 0):

I guess to use the join in sql so that you will have one statement:

```
SELECT * FROM second as second_tab LEFT join main as main_table ON main_table.post_id=second_table.post_id WHERE main_table.group_id="3"
```

Well not tested now but thats a way to solve some of your problems!